# Leetcode 2152, minimum Number of Lines to Cover Points. Fail at when x-axis is same

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, line

Here is solution that able to pass all test cases. I tried to convert it to javascript, but it fails this test case. (When 2 points have the same x-axis)

```
[[-4,0],[0,4],[-1,-5],[2,3],[-4,1],[-4,3],[-1,5]]

output: 4
expect: 3
```

If you don't have access: may have a look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-lines-cover-points/

```
class Solution:
    def minimumLines(self, points: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        slope_calc = lambda p1, p2: (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]) if p2[0] != p1[0] else math.inf

        def helper(lines, points):
            if len(points) == 0:
                return len(lines)
            
            point = points[0]
            
            
            # add to existing line            
            for p, slope in lines:
                s = slope_calc(point, p)
                if s == slope:
                    return helper(lines, points[1:])
            
            # if we have a single point and it doesn't belong to an existing
            # line, we must have another line to cover it.
            if len(points) == 1:
                return len(lines) + 1

            # creating new line in the case we have two or more points
            # (cover two at once). iterating through all possibilities.
            best = math.inf
            for i in range(1, len(points)):
                p = points[i]
                slope = slope_calc(point, p)
                lines.append((point, slope))
                best = min(best, helper(lines, points[1:i] + points[i + 1:]))
                lines.pop(-1)
            
            return best

        return helper([], points) if len(points) > 1 else 1
```

Here is my javascript

```
var cal_slope = function(p2, p1) {
    if(p2 !== p1) {
        return (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);    
    } else {
        return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    }
}

var dfs = function(lines, pts) {
    // base
    if(pts.length === 0) {
        return lines.length;
    }
    
    const curr_pt = pts[0];
    
    // existing can cover?
    for(let i=0; i<lines.length; ++i) {
        const line_pt = lines[i][0];
        const line_slope = lines[i][1];
        
        const new_slope = cal_slope(line_pt, curr_pt);
        if(new_slope === line_slope) {
            // can cover
            return dfs(lines, pts.slice(1));
        }
    } // el
    
    // cannot cover
    if(pts.length === 1) {
        return lines.length + 1;
    }
    
    
    let best = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    
    // form new slope
    for(let i=1; i<pts.length; ++i) {
        const pt = pts[i];
        const new_slope = cal_slope(pt, curr_pt);
        
        const line1 = lines.slice(0);
        line1.push([curr_pt, new_slope]);
        
        const p1 = pts.slice(1, i);
        const p2 = pts.slice(i+1);
        const newPts = [...p1, ...p2];
        
        best = Math.min(best, dfs(line1, newPts));
    } // el
    
    return best
}

var minimumLines = function(pts) {
    if(pts.length === 1) {
        return 1;    
    } else {
        return dfs([], pts);
    }
};
```

Comment: a visualizer https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if(p2 !== p1) {
```

In your use of the function, `p1` and `p2` are arrays with x and y coordinates. Such a comparison is only true when `p1` and `p2` are the same array reference. This is never the case in your use cases.

You need this (as is also the case in the Python version):

```
if(p2[0] !== p1[0]) {
```